# How to avoid automatic page refresh in ICEfaces?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, page-refresh

With each click on the button, the data table will refresh.
What do I need to change to avoid refreshing the dataTable?

```
<ice:dataTable id="dataList" style="width:100%;border-width:0px"
    columnWidths="30px, 100px;" border="1"
    value="#{bookService.model}" var="row" rows="25">

    <ice:column id="columnId">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText value="Lfd-Nr"></ice:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <center>
            <ice:outputText value="#{row.lfdNr}"></ice:outputText>
        </center>
    </ice:column>

    <ice:column id="columnTitle">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText value="Anrede" />
        </f:facet>
        <center>
            <ice:outputText value="#{row.anrede.anredeText}" />
        </center>
    </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>


<h:form id="formtest">
    <ice:commandButton id="btn" value="Click" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Problem is, that your list is binded by the model, which is lazily instantioned in its getter(?). When you submit the button, view and also the model is reloaded. What about to try some ajax button which should give you possibility to work out of jsf lifecycle (not submit a form)?

Answer (score 4):

What about to use [ajax button](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=commandButton&skin=blueSky) which should be "out" of jsf lifecycle (not submit a form)?

```
<a4j:commandButton value="click">
```

or with call some method from you `@ManagedBean` and rerender selected component (e.g.`form`):

```
<a4j:commandButton value="click" render=":form" execute="#{bean.some_method}"/>
```

**UPDATE:** (open a new window)

```
<a4j:commandButton value="new" onclick="window.open('new.xhtml','newWindow','width=600, height=600');"/>
```

Comment: The button will open a filter dialog. There may be different filter set. Is only when the filter is used to refresh the datatable.

Comment: You can try to use `onclick` attribute (see my updated answer), but I think it's a material for a new question. Anyway, if you find my answer useful, don't forget to accept it..